# Automated MSI installation

Tags: windows-installer, automated-tests, automated-deploy

What is the best way to automatically install an MSI file or installer .exe? We want to do some automated testing from our build system on the installed copy of the product. Our installer has the usual license acceptance screen, install location, etc.

---

As FryHard pointed out there are two options in particular that seem handy:

- "/quiet" - no use interaction
- "/passive" - process bar only, unattended mode

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To automate the installation of an MSI package, you can use the /I option, like this:

```
msiexec.exe /qn /i mypackage.msi
```

Keep in mind that you need to specify the properties the MSI package expect the user to specify through the UI, and for which it does not have a default value.

You can use the [Orca tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(v=vs.85).aspx) to see the list of properties and fiddle around with MSI conditions, etc. And to set values for the properties, you can just specify it in command line; e.g. to set a property ISDEBUG:

`msiexec.exe /qn /i mypackage.msi ISDEBUG=1`

**Side note**: To automate uninstall, use the /X option with the package or the product code:

```
msiexec.exe /qn /x mypackage.msi
```

or this (where you need to change the CLSID with your product code):

```
msiexec.exe /qn /x {B741B8A3-8DCB-44E0-B06F-2A11F56572DB}
```

Comment: Good, so how do you "specify certain (non-default) properties the MSI package might expect"?

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember. I haven't touched MSI in about five years.

Comment: To get errorMessages, you should create Installer Log.

Silent Command for it:
msiexec.exe /qn /i mypackage.msi ISDEBUG=1 /l*vx mypackageInstallerLog.txt

Answer (score 14):

If you head over to one of your MSI packages in the command prompt and run a:

```
Myproduct.MSI /?
```

A screen will pop up with all the details of command line parameters that you can pass to the MSI. I am sure that in this way you could install your application via a command prompt and in this way automate it.

Answer (score 0):

Is not released yet but could work for future references.

http://www.paulstovell.com/octopus/intro

Auto-deployment with nugget packages.