# How to make a .msi file that has no clickable screens (fully automated)?

Tags: c#, windows-installer, vdproj

I'm using a vdproj to create a .msi file.

I have a continuous integration server that needs to install our program on a dedicated machine. I'd like for it to run the .msi file yet have no clickable screens because I want to fully automate the process. So the .msi file when you double click it, should do it's thing, and when it's done will just exit. No next screens, no nothing.

Is this possible, and if so what is the easiest way to do this with vdproj?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create your standard MSI and run it with the silent switch.

```
msiexec /i myapp.msi /qn
```

Answer (score 2):

Set [LIMITUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369759%28VS.85%29.aspx) property to "1". It's not supported directly by Visual Studio, but you can add it in Property table with [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28VS.85%29.aspx).

This way the MSI will show only a progress bar during install when you double-click it.

Answer (score 1):

See [Automated MSI installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181342/automated-msi-installation)

Answer (score 0):

You could also create an MSI without any entries in the InstallUISequence.  When the MSI gets kicked off you'll see a generic windows progress bar, but it won't require any user interaction.