# Automate Installation of A Windows Application

Tags: automation, installation, white-framework

I have been working with UI Automation for quite a while now using White Framework for automation. The problem is since we get daily builds, so to run all the unit test I need that new installer to be run and the application installed on the server on which I have my Unit Test available. Is there any way within White FrameWork to automate installers? Does Record and Replay method for provided by Windows work? or is there any other way out?

Answer (score 1):

If you use windows installer, you might try something like this [Automated MSI installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181342/automated-msi-installation) to automate installation of msi packages.

Comment: That is one option. But I would still prefer to go with automation using white framework or using automation in VS. If that didn't work out then I would want to go with this option..

Comment: I need to know if its possible using automation using the above two techniques.