# get node.js for windows without msi

Tags: windows, node.js, bash

I'm writing a Windows script, which has to be run under Git-Bash (a Bash shell for Windows), that needs to download node.js from nodejs.org. This is an automated script so I'm using wget and using a url such as this

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.1/node-v0.10.1-x86.msi -O node-download.msi
```

The above line works by the way, but note that it grabs an msi. I need node.js itself and this is an automated script with no user interaction. There are ways to install an msi without user interaction (see [Automated MSI installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181342/automated-msi-installation)) but I need to specify the install directory. The question I just linked to never gets into how to specify values for the MSI installation rather than using the defaults. It would be simpler to download node.js directly; is there some reason on windows it *has* to be an MSI form? Does it have to alter values in the registry or something? If it does *have* to be an MSI, anyone know how to control the install directory, or at least find it after it's installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't verify that exact MSI right now since I'm on a mac, but normally, you set the installation directory using [`TARGETDIR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), something like;

```
msiexec /passive TARGETDIR="C:\MyInstallationDirectory" /i node-download.msi
```

(you may want to exchange `/passive` for `/quiet` if you want a silent installation)