# Coded UI Test Mouse.Click() does not work

Tags: c#, installshield, coded-ui-tests

I'm working on a Coded UI Test that tests the InstallShield Wizard for a program. At the beginning of the Wizard it installs some c++ Redistributable Packages and a popup window shows up that tells me it wasn't able to install the packages.

Now when I want to click the popups away the Mouse is able to move to the Control but can't click it. I've also tried to hover over the control and then click it but that also works. The Keyboard.SendKey() Method also doesnt work. And I also tried to skip the popup with the DesktopKeyboard.

The Funny thing is that this error occurs only for the popups for installing the c++ redistributable package and nowhere else.

I'm using Win10 and Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710589/how-to-install-software-automatically-with-coded-ui-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks I already fixed the problem by running VS as admin.